# VisibleDeprecationWarning specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray. arr_value = np.asarray(value)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, yfinance

I got the following error:

[image]

I would like to know where I have done wrong, thank you!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500'
headers = {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

request = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
data = pd.read_html(request.text)[0]
stk_list = data.Symbol
stk_list = data.Symbol.apply(lambda x: x.replace('.', '-'))
stk_list
```

```
import yfinance as yf
import time
stk_basic_data = yf.Ticker('AAPL').info
stk_basic_data
info_columns = list(stk_basic_data.keys())
stk_info_df = pd.DataFrame(index = stk_list.sort_values(), columns = info_columns)
failed_list = []

for i in stk_info_df.index:
    try:        
        print('processing: ' + i)
        info_dict = yf.Ticker(i).info
        columns_included = list(info_dict.keys())
        intersect_columns = [x for x in info_columns if x in columns_included]
        stk_info_df.loc[i,intersect_columns] = list(pd.Series(info_dict 
        [intersect_columns].values)
        time.sleep(1)
        
    except:
        failed_list.append(i)
        continue
```

Comment: After many tired, i solve this question - i have added below code: "np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning)", under the code: "info_dict - yf.Ticker(i).info.  Then it works.

Comment: While suppressing the warning works (note, it is just a warning, not an error), it hides an issue that you should deal with.  I was going to ask for a traceback to see where it occurs, but warnings don't provide that.  (changing the warnings filter to `error` would give the traceback.).  Building a ragged object dtype array unintentionally is wrong, and easily produce further problems.